# How to run queueing tuorial given with omnet++ installation?

Tags: queue, omnet++

I want to run the basic queueing model given with omnet++ installation.

in README.txt it is given as

> The "opp_run -l " command can be used to start simulations
>   where code is contained in shared libraries.

But on running this:

> $ opp_run -l queuenet

This is coming :

> OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2019 Andras Varga, OpenSim >Ltd.
>   Version: 5.5.1, build: 190613-08ba16f914, edition: Academic Public >License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
>   See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
>
> Error: Cannot open ini file 'omnetpp.ini'
>
> End.

What is right way to run these simulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ./queuenet
```

There is a shell script in that directory that starts the simulation for you in folder.